# edit out portions of a XML file inside an XSL `for-each` loop

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, foreach

I am trying to edit out portions of a XML file inside an XSL `for-each` loop.

I have an XML file with several templates, and the XSL file has a for-each loop to display all of them.

My goal was to eliminate certain templates from displaying within the XSL for-each loop by targeting individual templateId's inside the  node.

This is the code:

**XML**

```
<component typeCode="SEWS" contextConductionInd="true">
<section>
<templateId root="2.12.840.1.103883.13.20.23.2.68"/>
<code code="58907-0" codeSystem="1.33.890.1.176583.6.1" codeSystemName="GTRFC" displayName="Scenic Reports"/>
<title>Scenic Reports</title>
<text>
<table border="1" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Report</th>
<th>Value</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Source</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ID="GREETER_1">
<td ID="GREETER_1">Display Output1</td>
<td ID="GREETER_1">
<list>
<item>test data<br/>
</item>
</list>
</td>
<td>06/12/2019</td>
<td>Location TBD</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</text>
<entry typeCode="FRED" contextConductionInd="true">
<act classCode="FRE" moodCode="FRED">
<templateId root="2.12.840.1.103883.13.20.23.2.69" extension="2019-5-3"/>
<code code="34109-9" codeSystem="1.33.890.1.176583.6.2" codeSystemName="DEERS" displayName="FRED">
<!--Code must match or be equivalent to section code -->
<translation code="57898-0" codeSystem="1.33.890.1.176983.6.2" codeSystemName="DEERT" displayName="Scenic Reports"/>
</code>
<text>
<reference value="#DEERS_0"/>
</text>
<statusCode code="completed"/>
<effectiveTime value="547654653325.000"/>
<author>
<time value="4356754356.000"/>
<assignedAuthor>
<id nullFlavor="NA"/>
<addr nullFlavor="NA"/>
<telecom nullFlavor="NA"/>
<assignedPerson>
<name>Location TBD</name>
</assignedPerson>
<representedOrganization>
<id nullFlavor="NA"/>
<name>Location TBD</name>
<telecom nullFlavor="NA"/>
<addr nullFlavor="NA"/>
</representedOrganization>
</assignedAuthor>
</author>
</act>
</entry>
</section>
</component>
```

**XSL**

```
<xsl:template name="section">
<xsl:call-template name="section-title">
<xsl:with-param name="title" select="n1:title"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="section-author"/>
<xsl:call-template name="section-text"/>
<xsl:for-each select="n1:component/n1:section">
<xsl:call-template name="nestedSection">
<xsl:with-param name="margin" select="2"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I am wondering is we are able to edit out content in an XML document in an XSL for-each loop, based upon `<templateId root="1.1.5.33.4.33"...>`, or `<code code="87654-1"...>`.

I have tried `<xsl:if>` and `<xsl:choose><xsl:when>` statements to no avail.

Comment: Please show what your required output is. Also it would be much easier to read your XML if it was indented.

Comment: Not only the indentation, but just providing a single template from the stylesheet, is also confusing -- for example we don't see the called template named `nestedSection` `sectionTitle` and `sectionAuthor`. Also, there are no `xsl:if` and `xsl:choose` instructions in the provided XSLT code fragment? ?????

Please, provide the complete XSLT stylesheet, the complete result that you want to get from the transformation, the actual result you are getting, and what is the problem with the actual result.

Comment: It has become evident to me, and let me know if you agree, but the only way to filter out specific templates is filtering by nodes, and if all the templates share the same node (templateId) you cannot hide a specific template based upon the templateId i.e. <templateId root="2.12.840.1.103883.13.20.23.2.69" extension="2019-5-3"/>

Comment: @matt1966 You can certainly filter out what you want using the node name and a predicate containing its id or whichever other field you want. If you post a complete example of what you want you're more likely to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: I have a huge XML file that has multiple templates, but I only want some of them to show in the XSL output. The XSL has an existing for-each that loops through and shows all the templates. I want to filter out some of the templates in the XSL output based upon the unique templateId (<templateId root="1.1.5.33.4.33"...>)...

Comment: You can construct the shortest possible example that still illustrates the problem and post this -- no need for a long and original one.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try something like this :

```
<xsl:for-each select="templateId">
  <xsl:if test="not(@root='1.1.5.33.4.33' and @root='...somethingElse...')">
    ... your existing code ...
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or simply

```
<xsl:for-each select="templateId[not(@root='1.1.5.33.4.33' and @root='...somethingElse...')]">
  ... your existing code ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to use a <xsl: for-each> inside another <xsl: for-each>?

Comment: @matt1966 Yes you can do this.